# How to get all repeated regex patterns by beginning?

Tags: regex

Have got some server config:

```
((100010,test1.com,((Method,is,INVITE),(To,is,"0000000000*")),(("Redirect to","ccincoming#pbx@test1.com"))),(100010,test2.com,((Method,is,INVITE),(To,is,"00000000000*")),(("Redirect to","ccincoming#pbx@test2.com")),"some text"),(100010,test3.com,((Method,is,INVITE),("Submit Address","is not","LOCAL [0.0.0.0]*"),(Authenticated,is,"*@test3.com")),(("Redirect to","ccincoming#pbx@test3.com"),("Discard Rules"))),(100000,sometext,(("Submit Address",is,sometext)),(("Redirect to","ccincoming#pbx@sometext"),("Discard Rules"))),(100000,sometext,((Method,is,INVITE),(To,is,"00000000000*")),(("Redirect to","ccincoming#pbx@domain.com"))))
```

Need to get each pattern that starts with "(1000". and ends at the beginning of next.

Tried **"/(\(1000.*\)),\(1000/gU"**. But it gets only odd matches (once through).

So, need to get this:

- > (100010,test1.com,((Method,is,INVITE),(To,is,"0000000000*")),(("Redirect to","ccincoming#pbx@test1.com")))
- > (100010,test2.com,((Method,is,INVITE),(To,is,"00000000000*")),(("Redirect to","ccincoming#pbx@test2.com")),"some text")
- > (100010,test3.com,((Method,is,INVITE),("Submit Address","is not","LOCAL [0.0.0.0]*"),(Authenticated,is,"*@test3.com")),(("Redirect to","ccincoming#pbx@test3.com"),("Discard Rules")))
- > (100000,sometext,(("Submit Address",is,sometext)),(("Redirect to","ccincoming#pbx@sometext"),("Discard Rules")))
- > (100000,sometext,((Method,is,INVITE),(To,is,"00000000000*")),(("Redirect to","ccincoming#pbx@domain.com")))

Thanks for any help!

https://regex101.com/r/xciBIF/1

Comment: Which species of regex are you using?  Does it support lookahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that last part a lookahead, so that it doesn't eat into your next match:

`\(1000.*\)(?=,\(1000|\)$)`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/b7CRtQ/4)

Comment: Note that this will also match intermediate parts that do not start with 1000, if any

Comment: Thats it! Thank you!